# 'show x more comments` text's tooltip remains after clicking

Tags: bug, comments, tooltips

[image]

The tooltip give the impression that you have to click a (now) non-existent button to add a new comment, even though you don't have to.

To repro:

- get someone to post a comment
- click the `show x more comments` text that shows up
- move your cursor a bit below, as in the above image

You'll see the tooltip.

It seems, when you click this button, the div gets an added (unnecessary?) title attribute.

Compare a normal (without clicking the button):

```
<div id="comments-link-3122">
```

with (after clicking the button):

```
<div id="comments-link-3122" title="expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Any particular reason for this added attribute? Can it be removed please?

Gif:

[image]

Comment: Add a comment here?

Comment: @Tim here's a comment - but you need to make sure you see it 'live'...

Comment: Got it. reproduced!